# Toggle rows of a table inside while loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table with several buttons with "SHOW" text. Everytime I click one of those buttons I'd like that rows with class ".infotr" appears and when I click again the same button those rows disappear. (I mean the ".infotr" rows of the same table of the clicked button.)

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ID='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<table id='tablemodificamobile'>";
    echo "<tr id='firsttr'>";
    echo "<td id='amid' class='modificatd'>".$myid."</td>";
    echo "<td id='amtitle' class='modificatd'>".$row['Title']."</td>";
    echo "<td id='amshow' class='modificatd'><input type='button' id='mostramodbtn' value='SHOW'></input></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr class='infotr'><td class='addinfo'>New Price: ".$row['NewPrice']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class='infotr'><td class='addinfo'>Old Price: ".$row['OldPrice']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr class='infotr'><td class='addinfo'><input type='button' value='SAVE' id='modit'></input></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
  $('#mostramodbtn').click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").nextAll().show();
  });
```

Comment: Can you expand on "*it doesn't work*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click','#mostramodbtn',function() {
   $(this).parents("tr").nextAll().toggle("slow");
});
```

You are creating the element dynamically so you need to bind the even on document with `.on` function.

Learn more about [`.on()` function in jQuery here](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: use toggle instead of show. _rows with class ".infotr" appears and when I click again the same button those rows disappear_

Comment: @nada *I agree with you. there should be used `.toggle` function*.

Comment: Thank you. I used toggle but I changed it with show for the testing and I forgot to change show to toggle for the question.